# How can I solve the ImproperlyConfigured error in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I just started learning django and I'm getting the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

when running the command `from myApp.models import Dragons`. This is  ``models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Dragons(models.Model):
    rider = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dragon = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

This is `INSTALLED_APPS` inside `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myApp.apps.MyappConfig',
]
```

This is `àpps.py`:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class MyappConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'myApp.apps'
```

And this is the folder structure:
[image: Folder Structure]

**Solutions that didn't work:**

1. Restarting the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are just running `python`. You need to access shell as below.

```
python manage.py shell
```